# Promql K8S get pod counts on namespaces with specific annotation

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

Looking for a Prometheus query for this situation:

```
namespace A: has annotation ZZZ
namespace B: has annotation YYY
namespace C: has annotation ZZZ
```

how to query pods count for all namespaces with annotation ZZZ ?

Comment: you can filter base on label, did not find way for annotation

Answer (score 0):

As @adiii said there is no way to find using annotation . But if you need to get the number of pods per namespace, it'll be: `count(kube_pod_info{namespace="$namespace_name"}) by (namespace)` To get the number of all pods running on the cluster, then just do: count(kube_pod_info).
Don’t forget to change variable $Name_of_namespace to namespace name where you want to check.

Refer these [metric docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/pod-metrics.md) and change according to your query or need and also .